# HTML <select> options not showing with keyboard control when <label> is hidden or not present

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have a very simple `<select>` dropdown with two child `<option>`'s:

```
<div>
    <select>
        <option
            value="defaultPrice"
            selected
        >Price</option>
        <option
            value="title"
        >Title</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

When I use my mouse and click the select, I am shown the options context menu to select an option:

[image]

However, when I use my keyboard and focus the select element, the up and down keys will not bring up the same dialogue, as expected.

*However* when I add a label to my select, the up and down keys do show the context menu:

```
<div>
    <label for="my-select">Sort order</label>
    <select id="my-select">
        <option
            value="defaultPrice"
            selected
        >Price</option>
        <option
            value="title"
        >Title</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Then, if I then add CSS to hide the label, again the dropdown will not show.

This seems to be happening wherever I've been using select drop-downs, and only seems to be an issue in Chrome (v. 77.0.3865.90).

I have no CSS included in the site yet, so it's not a styling issue.

Has anyone else encountered such an issue? Unsure if it's a problem with my markup or a bug with Chrome.

Comment: Do you have a page online to test it ? Anyway you should always put a label for accessibility reasons, even if you place it off-screen with CSS (don't use display:none)

Comment: Yes, I've been adding labels and hiding them off screen for accessibility reasons described, (using position absolute and - 99999px) — however when I do this, the problem comes back and the dropdown doesn't show again, super weird.

Comment: Looks like a weird Chrome bug — this only happens when the window is in a tab group of other Chrome browser windows. If it's in a window of its own it works as expected. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The screenshot you show is styled so I am confused. I tried your code and it worked as expected in a JS fiddle, could you post the whole page code to a fiddle that you can recreate the issue on and I will have a look for you as i have a feeling it is an HTML error elsewhere (given your screenshot also shows 'Indoor' I am guessing there is more to the code than that shown here).

Comment: @GrahamRitchie the styling shown in the screenshot is Chrome default styling before any CSS added. Got to the bottom of the issue, and it's a weird Chrome bug which only happens when you have a window with multiple tabs open.

Comment: fair enough, guess it is a Mac only issue hence why I didn't recognise the styling. Glad you sorted it (kinda)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie haha well I guess I didn't sort it, but at least i didn't cause it either. ;) I'll log a but report with Chrome!